# Infinite expression: $\frac{2}{1} \times \frac{2}{3} × \frac{4}{3} × \frac{4}{5} × \frac{6}{5}...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

So there is this product
$\frac{2}{1} \times \frac{2}{3} × \frac{4}{3} × \frac{4}{5} × \frac{6}{5}...$

I got its expression of a general term but converting it into a sum by a logarithm doesn't help either. Also could we independently say whether a limit exists or not as $4r^2>4r^2-1$ ?

Comment: On a separate thing, could someone please tell me how to type matrices etc. in questions as I am new user.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You'll find this useful -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product

Comment: Yes ,thank you very much!

Comment: Sung Jin: there is a MathJax tutorial on the site, but this is way you do matrices (note that bmatrix/pmatrix/matrix are interchangeable commands just changing how the border is rendered): `\begin{\bmatrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\end{bmatrix}`. This will make: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Oh as in bold and plain.? Ok thank you very much

Comment: You can combine the terms to get the formula $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4n^2}{4n^2-1}$$ which definitely converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note you can write this as:

$$\prod_n \left(\frac {n+1}n\right)^{(-1)^{n-1}}.$$ Then the logarithm is $$\sum_n (-1)^{n-1}\log\left(1+\frac1n\right),$$ which converges since it is an alternating series that is decreasing in absolute value and converges to zero. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: Thank you for the link. This is a new thing to learn for me

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\ln\left(\frac k{k-1}\frac k{k+1}\right)=\ln \frac {k^2}{k^2-1}=\ln\left(1+\frac1{k^2-1}\right)<\frac1{k^2-1}
$$ so that the series of logarithms converges